# I can't download selenium because of Permissions

Tags: python, bash, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to install selenium, but it says I can't do it because of permissions.By the way I'm doing that on MacOS Mojave 10.14

I just entered ''brew reinstall selenium-server-standalone''and then it fails cause of permissions, you can see that in code part.

```
==> Reinstalling selenium-server-standalone 
==> Downloading https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.141/selenium-s
Already downloaded: /Users/temirhanzakirov/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/25a539ffe0543bae17e9cc5a70f6f187f973eb016e93696e667c6e4f6bbbf39a--selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
==> Caveats
To have launchd start selenium-server-standalone now and restart at login:
  brew services start selenium-server-standalone
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  selenium-server -port 4444
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/selenium-server-standalone/3.141.59: 5 files, 10.2MB, built in 2 seconds
MacBook-Pro-Temirhan:google-activity-gen temirhanzakirov$ python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: No module named selenium
MacBook-Pro-Temirhan:google-activity-gen temirhanzakirov$ pip install selenium
Collecting selenium
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/80/d6/4294f0b4bce4de0abf13e17190289f9d0613b0a44e5dd6a7f5ca98459853/selenium-3.141.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3 (from selenium)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/00/ee1d7de624db8ba7090d1226aebefab96a2c71cd5cfa7629d6ad3f61b79e/urllib3-1.24.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: urllib3, selenium
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/urllib3-1.24.1.dist-info'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Comment: It says **onsider using the `--user` option** did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

It's suggesting `pip install --user selenium`

To fix this, the homebrew docs suggest [the following](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python):

> Note on `pip install --user` The normal `pip install --user` is disabled
>   for brewed Python. This is because of a bug in `distutils`, because
>   Homebrew writes a `distutils.cfg` which sets the package prefix.
>
> A possible workaround (which puts executable scripts in
>   `~/Library/Python/<X>.<Y>/bin`) is:
>
> `python -m pip install --user --install-option="--prefix=" <package-name>`

Comment: Great! Mark as the answer so folks know that your issue was solved @noname

Answer (score 0):

First, run:

```
brew clean all && brew doctor
```

It looks like you're using the system Python instead of the homebrew one, so it may benefit you to:

```
brew install python
```

And make sure that `/usr/local/bin` is before `/usr/bin` in your `$PATH` environment variable.